eloquent function delete & update not working
I use eloquent for delete in my project with laravel8.it returns true but the records not remove from table.
what I try to do:
Package::findOrFail($id)->delete(); 

I have this problem on eloquent update too.
how I can sole this problem???

Are you using transactions? It sounds like you're not committing.

are you using SoftDeletes trait? https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#soft-deleting
